# Having two algorithms executing durign f(t) and g(t) can you prove f(t) = O(g(t))? How?

Tags: algorithm

I am taking algorithm and data structures class and I have to prove 
the following statement (on paper):

[image]

f(t) and g(t) are both algorithms.

Comment: `f` is quadratic (review the arithmetic series sum formula if you don't know why), and `g` is exponential. Since [polynomial < exponential](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55468), `f(t) = O(g(t))`.

Answer (score 0):

So f(t) will sum the numbers from 1 to n is equal to t(t+1)/2. It is element of Theta(t^2). Theta means that a function is asymptoticaly equal to an other function's function class. The g(t) is clearly an exponential, so it is Theta(5^t). Ordo means, that a function class (g(t)'s fc now) is asymptoticaly equals or bigger then the function we investigate (f(t)). Since f(t) is elements of Theta(t^2), it is also elements of any function class that asymptoticaly equals or bigger then t^2. Which means it is in the funcion class O(t^2), O(t^3),O(t!) etc. This means, f(t) is elements of O(5^t) because this O is bigger. Put it all together, f(t) is element of O(g(t))